# Can any video be embedded in a google map placemark InfoWindow?

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to embed an .avi or .flv video into a placemark InfoWindow that will be loaded or streamed from a server.  I was able to do this with Google Earth using a .kml file and was wondering if it is possible with google maps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

set up the content for the infowindow as shown below.
The iframe points to the streaming video.

var totollcontent = '' +
'' +
'Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.' +
'' +
'           '

This method works with IE and older firefox. I tried it with firefox 4 and it failed...
Never worked well with Chrome. doesnt work with safari.

Any help on a universally acceptable method will be much appreciated